# How do I connect a P-trap/standpipe to this hole in the wall?

Tags: plumbing, water

The flat I'm about to move into has no kitchen, and I'd like to fit a trap/standpipe [like this](https://mcalpineplumbing.com/traps/domestic-appliance-traps-accessories/wm3-112-standpipe-trap) to the wall so that I can use the dishwasher while waiting for our kitchen to be installed.

As far as I understand, the waste pipe is in the middle in this picture, but how do I connect the standpipe to it?

[image: wall fittings]

There seems to be a rubber seal running around the inside, roughly 5 mm in size. I can't make out any thread or other interface inside or out.

[image: seal]

Comment: Please show a photo of the pipe, not drywall texture. What are we looking at?

Comment: @isherwood I've added a more detailed photo. Looks like there's a rubber seal of some sort.